# Android simple_list_item_single_choice set default height programatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using simple_list_item_single_choice for my listview items.

Here is sample code

```
view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, null);
final CheckedTextView title = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

This works nice, but my listview items are not displayed nicely...what I mean is that height of items is exactly content height...
I want it to be padded like if I use simple_list_item1 but I need it to be with choice radio.

How can I set this nice minimum height? It should be by default `48 dip`
Tried to set `title.setMinimumHeight(48)` but with no luck.

EDIT: I know that this is possible with custom layout but it is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice create your custom layout and use. In custom layout you can set height and width easily.

Comment: Yes I know that but why create custom layout if I only want to show list with selection...and single_choice is doing exactly what I need just want to mage items little bigger

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late, and maybe you solve this problem... I solved the problem as follows :

```
int getListViewHeight(ListView list) {
    ListAdapter adapter = list.getAdapter();

    list.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int listviewHeight = list.getMeasuredHeight() * adapter.getCount() + (adapter.getCount() * list.getDividerHeight());

    return listviewHeight;
}
```

Use :

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewId);
listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getListViewHeight(listView)));
```

The Listview should be in LinearLayout. If in a different layouts, must be modified to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Good coding :)